# How to add a User Entity as a Field in Content Type?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

How to add a User Entity as a Field in a Content Type?

So I can be able to display First/Last Name field.

Comment: Hello! can you please clarify? 1) What is the name of your content type (for clarity)? 2) Did you want to link users to the content type? or did you just want another textfield in the content type?

Comment: @JapoDomingo Updated..

Comment: Oh so you want to link the user that created the node to the content? That association is already there. Is the end goal to display the author's name on the article?

Comment: @JapoDomingo But i want user see his name BEFORE submit save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the name of the author is already displayed in the Author information section in one of the tabs at the bottom of the form.

HOWEVER, if you really want to display the username of the logged in user for some reason, you can use `hook_form_alter`.

Create this in a custom module OR in your theme's template.php, if you won't be doing much customisation.

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Use drupal_set_message($form_id); to figure out the form id 
  // of the article edit form.
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    global $user;
    // Check the content of the $form using dsm() or krumo().
    // You will have access to these functions if you have the devel module enabled.
    // Then insert your item into the form.
    $form['username'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => 'Username',
      '#value' => $user->name,
      // Adjust the weight so your field will appear in the order you like.
      '#weight' => 10,
    );

  }

}
```

Take note that this will NOT change the author of the form. To change that you have to actually alter the fieldset for author.

Reference:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x